# Resultset always empty when doing executeQuery

Tags: java, jdbc

I am currently writing a simple Java app that reads information from an XLS file and then enters it in the database. Since that XLS does have duplicated records, I do a simple check if the entry in the XLS file already exists in the database. Here is my code:

```
public static void addResult(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listResults)
{
    try
    {
        openDatabase();
        stmt = c.createStatement();

        for (int i = 0; i < listResults.size(); i++)
        {
            PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement("SELECT player_name FROM results WHERE player_name=?;");
            stm.setString(1, listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.NAME));
            System.out.println(stm);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

            if (rs.getRow() <= 0)
            {
                String typeOfPlay = new String();

                if (listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.TYPE).equals("Simple"))
                {
                    typeOfPlay = "single";
                }
                else if (listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.TYPE).equals("Double"))
                {
                    typeOfPlay = "double";
                }

                stm = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO results (player_name, school_id, " +  typeOfPlay + ", tournament_id) "
                        + "VALUES(?,?,?,?);");

                stm.setString(1, listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.NAME));
                stm.setString(2, listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.SCHOOL_ID));
                stm.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.SCORE)));
                stm.setString(4, "1");
                stm.executeUpdate();
            }
            else
            {
                String typeOfPlay = new String();

                if (listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.TYPE).equals("Simple"))
                {
                    typeOfPlay = "single";
                }
                else if (listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.TYPE).equals("Double"))
                {
                    typeOfPlay = "double";
                }

                stm = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE results SET " + typeOfPlay + "=? WHERE player_name=?;");

                stm.setString(1, typeOfPlay);
                stm.setString(2, listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.SCORE));
                stm.setString(1, listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.NAME));
                System.out.println(stm);
                stm.executeUpdate();
            }
        }

        closeDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The problem that arises is that the rs.getRow() function always returns -1. I tried running the SELECT query directly in the database tool and the query returns the player_name column if there is already a similar entry existing. It unfortunately do the same in Java.

I am unsure what to do at this point.

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: make sure that `listResults.get(i).get(ReadResultsFile.NAME)` does not have any trailing spaces.  In fact I would chuck into a String and print it out.  Also not relevant I think, but the `;` in the sql is not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getRow will not work as per the javadocs

> Retrieves the current row number. The first row is number 1, the second number 2, and so on.

and

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row

Usually use

```
while (rs.next ()) {....
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!